# want to delete recycler list item on drop to delete imageview. Delete imageview is defined in activity

Tags: android

I am working on drag and drop and now implementing delete functionality just like launcher application.
I am making my delete image visible on selection of recycler item but not able to delete recycler item via dragging and dropping it on the delete image. 
I am using Itemtouchhelperadapter and collections for selection and dragging of recycler items.

```
    public RecyclerListAdapter(Context context, OnStartDragListener dragStartListener) {
    mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
    mItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dummy_items)));
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    v = parent;
    trashView = (ImageView)v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.main_trash);
    trashView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.v("inside","ontouch");
            return false;
        }
    });
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
    ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(mItems.get(position));

    // Start a drag whenever the handle view it touched
    holder.handleView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(mItems, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

    public final TextView textView;
    public final ImageView handleView;
    ImageView trashView;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        handleView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.handle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected() {
        trashView = (ImageView)v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.main_trash);
        trashView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        TextView tv = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        selectedText = tv.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClear() {
        ((ImageView)v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.main_trash)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any event while dragging and taking my recycler items to the delete image. I have tried Ontouch and onHover listener but no use.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: trashView is the image where i am dragging my recycler items for deletion

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is full of trial and error, you should clean it from anything unneccessary.

First, you need a `CoordinatorLayout` wrapping your existing Layout, give it an `Id`, and initialize it in your `Activity/Fragment`, also implement `View.OnDragListener` and implement its required method. More on this later. :)

Second, call set the `onDragListener`:

```
    coordinatorLayout.setOnDragListener(this);
```

Add `implements View.OnLongClickListener`to your `Adapter`, implement the required method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    v.startDrag(ClipData.newPlainText("label", v.getTag().toString()), new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Set the `tag` and the `onLongClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this); 
}
```

Here is the `onDrag` method, where all the magic happens:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    /*
    * You need to know the `Rect` (Rectangles) aka, the shape of your dragged `View` and your `View`, where you want to drop it.
    */

    Rect draggedImageRect = new Rect();
    Rect trashRect = new Rect();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            /*
            * The magic happens here. The user dragged your `View` to the `trashImage` and drops it:
             */

            float oldX = v.getX();
            float oldY = v.getY();
            v.setX(event.getX());
            v.setY(event.getY());
            v.getHitRect(draggedImageRect);
            trashImage.getHitRect(trashRect); //change trashImage with your variable

            /*
            * More magic happens here. We need to make sure, that only the drop to the trash will delete the dragged item.
            */
            if (Rect.intersects(draggedImageRect, trashRect)) {
                try {
                    int pos = Integer.parseInt(event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString());

                    yourList.remove(pos);
                    yourAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            v.setX(oldX);
            v.setY(oldY);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```